# Trait value not being set after Symfony 3.4 upgrade (from 2.8)

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, traits, symfony-3.4

I am going a Symfony 2.8 to 3.4 LTS upgrade. I am getting the following error when using my `TranslatorTrait` which is injected into my `BreadCrumbExtension`.

```
In TraitManager.php line 28:

  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]                
  User Error: Value has not been set for AppBundle\Traits\TranslatorTrait  

Exception trace:
 AppBundle\Traits\TraitManager::_traitValue() at /private/var/www/crmpicco/symfony/src/AppBundle/Traits/TranslatorTrait.php:25
 AppBundle\Twig\BreadCrumbExtension->getTranslator() at /private/var/www/crmpicco/symfony/src/AppBundle/Twig/BreadCrumbExtension.php:45
 AppBundle\Twig\BreadCrumbExtension->__construct() at /private/var/www/cache/dev/ContainerGijxtqp/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php:1501
 ContainerGijxtqp\appDevDebugProjectContainer->getTwigService() at /private/var/www/cache/de_/ContainerGijxtqp/getTwig_CacheWarmerService.php:9
 ContainerGijxtqp\appDevDebugProjectContainer->{closure}() at /private/var/www/crmpicco/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ServiceLocator.php:64
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ServiceLocator->get() at /private/var/www/crmpicco/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/CacheWarmer/TemplateCacheCacheWarmer.php:63
 Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\CacheWarmer\TemplateCacheCacheWarmer->warmUp() at /private/var/www/crmpicco/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/CacheWarmer/CacheWarmerAggregate.php:52
 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\CacheWarmer\CacheWarmerAggregate->warmUp() at /private/var/www/crmpicco/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/CacheClearCommand.php:222
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\CacheClearCommand->warmup() at /private/var/www/crmpicco/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/CacheClearCommand.php:134
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\CacheClearCommand->execute() at /private/var/www/crmpicco/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:255
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /private/var/www/crmpicco/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:964
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /private/var/www/crmpicco/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:86
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /private/var/www/crmpicco/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:248
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /private/var/www/crmpicco/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:74
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at /private/var/www/crmpicco/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:148
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /private/var/www/crmpicco/symfony/bin/console:27

cache:clear [--no-warmup] [--no-optional-warmers] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command>
```

`services.yml`:

services:

```
_defaults:
    # automatically injects dependencies in your services
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: false

    # makes classes in src/AppBundle available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../../../src/AppBundle/*'
        # you can exclude directories or files
        # but if a service is unused, it's removed anyway
        exclude: '../../../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository}'

    AppBundle\Twig\BreadCrumbExtension:
        arguments:
            - '@service_container'
            - '@request_stack'
        autowire: false
        calls:
            - [setTranslator,             ['@translator']]
```

I tried flicking the service to `autowire: false` but it has no effect. What is wrong with my service definition?

`TranslatorTrait.php`:

```
namespace AppBundle\Traits;

use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;

trait TranslatorTrait
{
    /**
     * @param TranslatorInterface $translator
     */
    public function setTranslator(TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {
        TraitManager::_traitValue(__TRAIT__, $translator);
    }

    /**
     * @return TranslatorInterface
     */
    public function getTranslator(): TranslatorInterface
    {
        return TraitManager::_traitValue(__TRAIT__);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your TranslatorTrait here?

Comment: @QuentinDequippe Thanks for the comment. I have updated my question.

Comment: I think I will need your TraitManager also :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was to refactor out the `TraitManager` and use the `@required` annotation inside each trait as per below:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Traits;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

trait ContainerInterfaceTrait
{
    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    protected $containerInterface;

    /**
     * @required
     * @param ContainerInterface $value
     */
    public function setContainerInterface(ContainerInterface $value)
    {
        $this->containerInterface = $value;
    }

    /**
     * @return ContainerInterface
     */
    public function getContainerInterface(): ContainerInterface
    {
        return $this->containerInterface;
    }
}
```